# Will this MOSFET allow the heat bed to run at a different voltage than the control board

Tags: heated-bed, power-supply, mosfet

I am currently running my Tronxy X5s with a MKS Gen L board. So far I have not ran the heat bed over 50 degrees C since I have only printed with PLA so far. I plan to try PETG and/or ABS in the near future and I have a spare power supply 12V/360W laying around.

When I first got my printer I purchased [this](http://www.lerdge.com/prod_view.aspx?TypeId=12&Id=212&FId=t3:12:3) external MOSFET board after reading about X5s "upgrades", but so far have not used it.

[image]
[image]

My plan is to now run the heat bed using a separate power supply than the one running my control board using the external MOSFET to switch it. Since this power supply will only be powering the bed, I would like to bump up the voltage, via trim-pot somewhere from 12V-15V, to gain some watts per square inch on my heat bed.

Will this MOSFET isolate the heat bed circuit from my control board to allow it be ran at a higher voltage? Is it safe to run the power supply/heat bed at a higher voltage than it is rated for a significant amount of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer YES. You can run it from a different power supply at a higher voltage. Also it has a PC817 Optical isolator (for some reason) therefore the second power supply and your main board should not be electrically connected at all.

Comment: Where did you find the information on the PC817?

Comment: I looked up the board online, zoomed in on the image then googled the numbers. This resulted in a link to the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but you should be aware that **running at higher voltage implies that the current also increases**. Your wiring and connectors to the heated platform have to be able to transport that extra current (e.g. the wires, the ones I got where very low quality, and [connectors](https://3dprint.wiki/reprap/anet/a8/replace_hb_connector) that came with my Anet A8 where not even rated for the standard load, let alone an even higher load). You need to properly solder the leads to the heated bed and use proper terminal clamps ([C-clamps or forks](/a/6385/)) to connect the cables to the MOSFET module. Even running the basic voltage this can happen:

[image: Burnt Anet A8 connector using standard voltage]

Let's assume the heated bed has a resistance (R) of about 1.4 Ω. A voltage (U) of 12 V would result in a current (I) of $ I=\frac{U}{R}=\frac{12}{1.4} = 8.6\  A$ (Ampere). Running the same bed at 15 V would result in a current of $ \frac{15}{1.4} = 10.7\  A$. The power would increase from about 102 Watt to 161, which is a 60 % increase of a 25 % increase in voltage.

Comment: ...and so long as the thermistor is working nothing should catch fire.

Comment: @user77232 The working of the thermistor has nothing to do with that, connectors and wires could burn anyway due to not being rated for the current. There are examples where it did go wrong.

Comment: You'll have that problem no matter what voltage you run at. Bad connectors are bad at any voltage.

Comment: ... and good connectors become bad connectors when you are overpowering them.

Answer (score -2):

For reference,I done tracing this module as shown.
[image]
[image]
So you can use isolated power supply for load.
Also you can use up to 24V without any problem.
Edit:
This module still work with higher voltage up to 24V. But according to question. Using higher voltage supply more than rated is same as my question [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/can-we-apply-more-voltage-to-a-pcb-heated-bed-to-get-faster-heating).
For summary. Adding more voltage to resistive load results to higher current flow. Recheck your wire and connectors for current rate so you will know the limit of voltage you can go with.
One more thing, mosfet can fail like short circuit. At this situation the temperature of bed cannot be controlled.
At normal voltage rate even we left the bed connected to power supply the temperature will rising to about 100C if you add more voltage it will go higher than that can the heated bed will broken or burned or start to fires

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a wise answer: "`use up to 24V without any problem`" Although you can supply 24 V, you need to make sure all connectors and cables can handle that current increase. I know it is possible as I have turned a 12 V bed into a 24 V bed, but that is only possible when you do more changes than just upping the voltage to 24.

Comment: @0scar My bad. I mean if we supply 24V to module the module still working fine